What is the best approach to build an arbitrage bot?
So i'm currently building an arbitrage bot. My current approach is to get a quote from Jupiter Swap API V6 and execute the transaction if token's price discrepancy is above 0.6%. However I have two problems:
1. Price discrepancy is oftenly too low.
A 0.6% price discrepancy is super rare in my case (I try multiple different tokens, and not much different). If I execute anything below 0.6%, I'm not in net profit as I have to consider the fee, tip and slippage. I've been thinking about this problem and assumed that this is because of Jupiter algorithm (who try to get the best route) and hence the problem existed.
2. Transaction speed is too slow.
I've used JITO and still can't land transaction below 5 seconds. I tip in 99th percentile and not much different.
What is the possible solution to my problem? I've been thinking of manually scanning the price discrepancy across DEXes, but I'm worried about the execution time as this approach require at least 3 transactions (Buy at DEX A, Transfer to DEX B, Sell at DEX B), not to mention if the transaction is not landed at all! Anyone has build arbitrage bot before? I need an advice, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Just giving you a heads up from my past experience with this approach. You are going to want a very high-end bare metal VM based in a location that is close to gRPC and RPC providers. the gRPC and RPC costs alone will run you about $1000/month , so ensure you have plenty of capital to trade with to make up for it.
